# Send HTML image email in python

Tags: python, base64, html-email, email-attachments, data-uri

I am trying to send HTML email with inline image but the image is not coming, for some system, it's working fine and image is showing but for some it's not coming, Check the attached image for reference.
[image: Sample image error occuring]

And I also trying bypassing image using data uri

```
<td>
    <img style="display:block;"   src ="{{ image_tag }}" alt="check" 
    width="100%"></p>
</td>
data_uri= base64.b64encode(open('C://Users//Desktop//work.png', 
'rb').read()).decode('utf-8')
image_tag = "data:image/png;base64,"+ data_uri
with open('C://Users//Desktop//final.html', encoding='utf-8-sig') as myfile:
    outerdata=myfile.read()
    template = Template(outerdata)
    finalpage=template.render(image_tag = image_tag)
```

Comment: Many email clients don't support base64 encoding

Comment: You have to include it as an attachment, the link to it using the cid

Answer (score 0):

As mousetail said, many email clients do not support base64 encoding https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-base64/

You are almost correct with the following:

```
<td> <img src="C:\Users\Desktop\work.png" alt="Capgemini" style="display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"> </td>
```

But upload the image to the internet first, in a publicly available place (i.e. some website). Then the src should be `src="https://www.somewhere.com/image.png"`

It is unstated, but, picking up on your margin-left and right, if you want the image to be centered you should do that on a block element, rather than trying to change `<img>` to a block. The reason is that Outlook desktops do not support changing inline elements to block or vice-versa.